# Click or scroll?

Tags: scrolling, click, blog

I have a photoblog (http://www.rafaquesada.com/photoblog/) since already almost 3 years. I've been working on it since then trying to improve the visualisation and the experience on it.

Right now I show a max of 10 post per page, where a post can have one or several pictures. But since some weeks ago I'm thinking to reduce that number to 1, so just showing one post per page. This means that the user will need to click (or use the arrows of the keyboard or swipe in mobile; everything already there) to see the next post.

I know that scroll is easy and nowadays quite friendly as well. And also that clicking is a bit annoying and it means "wait".

But in the other hand, the experience by showing only one post can be improved a lot in the way of focusing just in one picture or group of related pictures.

What of the two options are better in this case?

Comment: Would it be possible (money/time wise) for you to just _try_ it? I mean, allowing the user to participate in some kind of beta test, and then ask them how they liked it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regular pagination vs. infinite scroll](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/15982/regular-pagination-vs-infinite-scroll)

Comment: I like that idea @DonL. Maybe it is an idea duplicate the site and try to get some feedback from the users (hope users will participate!).

Comment: @ekapros I am not talking about infinite scrolling

Comment: With content like photos this is really as much an aesthetic or artistic question as it is user experience. A general rule is that too many points of focus distract and can overwhelm the user. Photos stacked on top of each other does not necessarily mean that, but maybe the same idea of displaying less to better capture the users' focus is at the core of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all for your answers, all of them have made me think and create my own solution.

Basically I create a Homescreen with only one post, where you can navigate via clicking or using the keys (this option needs to be notify to the user soon) and AJAX added. But inside of categories or search results I show 10 results (as it was before).

I think with this option the user has a more focus in one picture/post/history, so more like in a "exhibition". As soon the user goes to any category or search, it will be easier to see the post there by showing 10 per page.

What do you think?

Comment: since it's a photo blog with basically no textual information I say "go for it". It's art - the visual experience may be way more important than the navigational structure.

Answer (score 0):

It depends of the number of photos within a group. Personally, I find it hard to recognize the groups with a lot of photos. Better you can show a photosheet (with e.g. 4 photos) if a post contains a group of photos. It's easier to find a specific shooting.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyGBQ1.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Another solution (idea): you can use sliders for a group of photos...

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRQvCT.png)</sup>

Comment: The thing is I want to keep consistency and simplicity with the tablet and mobile version, avoiding sliders and dont easy layouts to implement it

Comment: OK. That's right. Scrolling is good, but I would avoid an extremly large scrolling area. Another approach could be, teasing a group of photos with 3 photos. To see more photos of this shooting user can click on a link/button "Show more".

Answer (score 0):

Scrolling is better option because in case of clicking, person has to find right button to go next/forward
and scrolling makes user's overall experience far better than ckicking
it is far easier than clicking

Comment: "person has to find right button to go next/forward" - I doubt that's the problem... Users aren't that stupid. It's more likely that the user is annoyed if he's searching for a particular post or if he has bad internet connection

Comment: It can be a better option, but I have the feeling that in a photoblog if you have a set of post per page (for example 10), you will scroll and scroll and don't really focus in the pictures itself. With the other way I think the experience can be more "personal".