# Is Pagination necessary in grid?

Tags: grid, pagination

Is pagination necessary on grid with lots of data? The column in the grid I'm working on will be added after user click on the button to add new column and editing can be done in every column. It is not like those grid that return search results so I'm still wondering if pagination is appropriate in my case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular pagination vs. infinite scroll](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/15982/regular-pagination-vs-infinite-scroll)

Comment: @Keno, to be honest I don't see the relation between this question and the one mentioned as possible duplicate. However, I think this question needs a lot more information, such as a wireframe or any kind of visual aid. As it is right now, it could mean lots of different things

Comment: to the OP: please include more information. As you can see in the current answers and comments, everybody is understanding something different, basically because you didn't make any effort in providing a question we can answer. As such, this question is impossible to answer. In your particular case I'm tempted to answer NO for a variety of reasons, but without further information, it would be as much of a valid answer as any of the answers that says YES. As you can see, you can get totally opposed answers

Comment: @Devin: The core question is whether to use or not pagination, I am not sure there is a master **when to use pagination question already** , but that question is the closest I could find, also yeah it should be clearer.

Answer (score 1):

If you 'n' no.of grids then in my opinion pagination is necessary. You can limit te no.of grids to be shown in page. It would be easy for user to check.

In case of lazy load/infinite scroll user has to scroll to track that particular grid.

https://uxplanet.org/ux-infinite-scrolling-vs-pagination-1030d29376f1#.yf9ijkpa8

Answer (score 0):

Alternatives to Grid pagination are [scrolling](http://demos.shieldui.com/web/grid-general/scrolling) and [virtual scrolling](http://demos.shieldui.com/web/grid-virtualization/local-data) (when the row number is too high).

Answer (score -3):

If there are thousands of rows, or even few hundred, I suggest that one uses pagination. It is much more user friendly.