# Horizontal scrolling or show more?

Tags: lists, scrolling, cards

I'm working for a company and I have to make a section of a webpage that includes projects. They have 72 active projects and they want to show all of them in cards. The functionalities that include are editing the information of the project and adding new members, however I don't know if I use horizontal scrolling or a see more option in order to see the 72 projects.

I will be very grateful if you can give me your opinion and comments please.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regular pagination vs. infinite scroll](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/15982/regular-pagination-vs-infinite-scroll)

Answer (score 1):

Many users will scroll horizontally if the design encourages them to do so. However, with 72 cards, they will get lost very quickly, whether horizontal or vertical. I would suggest you consider filter and sort controls to reduce the number of options visible and scrollable.

Comment: In addition to the above response, I would suggest presenting the projects in groups. So the company can define the groups as default view to simplify the scrolling interaction, and if the users really want to find one specific project they can search for the project they are after.

Answer (score 0):

"See more options" button is interesting.

Because the action is affordable and the user understands that he has to click to load more.

While a scroll may be tricky because many don't notice it.