# Pagination vs Scroll in is iOS apps (ecommerce)

Tags: ios, scrolling, pagination

Do you have any detailed study on expected navigation patterns in iOS applications, especially in ecommerce apps?

We are designing a photo shoot & order application and I would like to get to know that pagination or scrolling would be preferred by iPhone users nowadays.

Comment: See this post - http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/7254/in-what-situations-would-pagination-be-perferable-over-scrolling-on-the-iphone?rq=1

Comment: pagination or scrolling for what part of the app ? on what screen exaclty , etc ...

Answer (score 0):

Why about combining both? You can make the list scrollable and add buttons for navigation ("Next 100" for example). Best of two worlds.

Answer (score 0):

Scrolling is definitely easier and less of a hassle when it comes to mobile devices, especially when it comes to browsing. Both Amazon's and Ebay's mobile app uses infinite scrolling for example.

The only problem with scrolling is its lack of ability to communicate location of where the user is and where they are heading.

One way of fixing this may be to load 20 items at a time and keep a tracker "Viewing 40-60 of 100" text when they load a new section.