# Best practice for displaying no of records on datagrid

Tags: navigation, design-patterns, pagination, data, data-tables

I am designing a banking application where i have a record count of over 1000 rows. I wanted to understand the ideal design patterns for pagination and displaying rows on a data grid.

I am considering using pagination control

1) by giving #of records to display (10/25/50/75/100)

2) by having previous/next

3) by virtual scrolling

Can you tell me what is the good UX pattern for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Michael Zuschlag says in his [great reply](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/1858/4679) to the question "[Is scrolling better than clicking to reveal more content?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1850/is-scrolling-better-than-clicking-to-reveal-more-content)":

> Paging should be used to break content into semantic or task-related groups of content, such as by your categories in your menu bar on the left. This allows users to find content by what it is (e.g., the page title in a menu) rather than where it is (e.g., page number or relative position in a scrolling page). Generally user tasks depend on what (“I need to check sports”) not where (“I need to check channels two-thirds down the list”).

In your case, you need to find smaller logical (related) entities or filters to enable users to quicker find the information they’re needing. By Time (month/week/day), by account type, by account holder or any other logical content separation would do.
But paginating a list of the same thing is a bad idea. Try to avoid it if you can.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I agree with you, paginating the whole chunk is not good idea. I am already having some filters where the user can do boolean operation over the data.

Comment: @Ravi Filters are really useful. You could also add a control which resets all filters. That way users feel certain that they are viewing all available data without having to reset each filter itself.

Answer (score 2):

If you absolutely have to have pagination at all I'd suggest something that is quite flexible and lets users do most of what they could want... perhaps something like this?

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcanbs.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

This lets them easily know how many results there are, change the amount viewed per page, navigate using next and previous or jump to a specific page. This way at least makes the pagination a little less painful, but filters and reducing massive amounts of information being shown is always the preference. I'm just suggesting this in case technology or other restraints force pagination to be used.