# How to determine display counts in a table?

Tags: pagination, data-tables

Context: I have tabular data in a table that populates dynamically so there could be any number of rows in the table. I do not wish to bombard the user with a long
scrolling page so I'd like to set breakpoints in the table and use a display count dropdown so the user can select how many rows show in the table per page.

Here's an example of what I'm talking about:

[image]

Question:

How do you determine the breakpoints?

Do you increment by 10,25,50,100,500,1000? or 10,100,1000?

Is there a general rule of thumb or best practice?

Note: Auto-load on scroll will not work in this case as the quantity of data the user sets can be exported under a WYSIWYG model.

Comment: There is no max for this as it's determined by the user's settings. They set the date and increment for the data. It could be anything from a few hundred rows to 100,000s. If the user selects Hourly breakdown over the course of 3 months, that's over 20k entries.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best practice for displaying no of records on datagrid](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/25309/best-practice-for-displaying-no-of-records-on-datagrid)

Comment: Just took a look at the link and it doesn't quite answer what I'm looking for. My question is about what specific increments to use as best practice, not about how to display.

Comment: @CodeMaverick not a duplicate - that question seeks to choose between three different styles, one of which is this customisable pagination method ... but doesn't address the question of what size buckets to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a study by the NNGroup that talks about [User's Pagination Preference](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/item-list-view-all/):

> Many sites let users choose how many items they’ll see on each page. This is often overkill, as when pop-up menus let users View 10, 20, 30, 40 items per screen.

...

> It’s usually better to offer a single default number—such as 10 or 20—and supplement it with View All for people who want more...this design requires only a simple button and is thus much faster to operate.

...

> if View All would generate an unwieldy page, give users the choice between two numbers, say 10 and 50, where the second number is substantially bigger than the default.