# Alternatives to scrolling to display long text?

Tags: website-design, layout, scrolling, pagination

As you can see on the picture below, my text is displayed within a 'relatively small' DIV. Currently users have the possibility to scroll down within the DIV to read the full text but I don't really like that solution and I'm looking for something more visually appealing. What would you advise in this case? Something like hide/show DIVs when users click on "text part 2", "text part 3, etc? Many thanks
[image]

Comment: Hi Greg, welcome to UX.se! Are you talking about pagination? If yes, have you looked at any of the pagination questions. They answer your question in detail, from what I can see. http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/36394/when-is-it-better-to-paginate-and-not-to-paginate

Answer (score 4):

When dealing with text, you have one of two options: a single (possibly long) page, or many pages.

**Scrolling** is basically a single very long page where you only see a window on it at a time.

**Pagination** (which can include scrolling if each page is long) is the same as having many pages.